# Hidden Markov Models and How to Interpret Probability of the Overall Sequence?

Tags: r, hidden-markov-model

What can I do to improve the probability of a sequence given my data?

Consider the following MWE:

```
# Initialise HMM
hmm = initHMM(c("A","B"), c("L","R"), transProbs=matrix(c(.8,.2,.2,.8),2),
              emissionProbs=matrix(c(.6,.4,.4,.6),2))
print(hmm)
# Sequence of observations
observations = c("L","L","R","R")
# forward
logForwardProbabilities = forward(hmm,observations)
forwardProbabilities = exp(logForwardProbabilities)
# probability of sequence
sum(forwardProbabilities[,4])
# 0.058276
```

The probability of the overall sequence here is very low, at .05. Should I then be very distrusting of this model given that the probability is so low?

Separately, to represent the confidence of a predicted state at any time step, is it fair to use the posterior (see below)?

```
# Initialise HMM
hmm = initHMM(c("A","B"), c("L","R"), transProbs=matrix(c(.8,.2,.2,.8),2),
              emissionProbs=matrix(c(.6,.4,.4,.6),2))
print(hmm)
# Sequence of observations
observations = c("L","L","R","R")
# Calculate posterior probablities of the states
posterior = posterior(hmm,observations)
print(posterior)

      index
states         1       2       3         4
     A 0.6037344 0.56639 0.43361 0.3962656
     B 0.3962656 0.43361 0.56639 0.6037344
```

The overall sequence predicted probability is very low, but the model strongly believes that at the last time step, 4, there is a 60% chance it is at state B, as compared to state A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a state sequence probability is indeed quite low (in the context of your small example of length 4 where there is only 16 possible sequences...).

A longer sequence might improve the infered sequence probability (not in absolute value, but opposed to the other sequences' probabilities) because you would generate a chain which reflects a strong markovian dependence. With your current parameters, you have 80% chances to stay in the same state as the previous one, this is a strong assumption that is not really used with such a small sequence of length 4.
You might also improve the probability by modifying the emission probabilities to something more different than the equiprobable law. That way, an observation would be linked to a hidden state with a greater probability, which would thus increase the overall sequence probability.

Yes the posterior at each time step is a good way to see the confidence of the model in its decision.

Comment: Thanks for your time and insight!